# Fixed Positioning Problems

Tags: html, css

In my sidebar there is no text showing up. This is what I see [Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwzfJ.png)

```css
.sidebar{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    padding: 100% 5%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
<h1>Sales</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overly padding the text.  You have padding set to 100%, which means, 100% of the page width, and this is for an element that only takes up 20% of the page, so, the text is probably far far far offscreen.  You probably don't want this.

Here, I have updated it to 0%, which now shows the text, so you can set padding correctly now as needed...

```css
.sidebar{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    padding: 0% 5%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
<h1>Sales</h1>
</div>
```